# Calculating $\left\Vert \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_n-\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} x_n}{2^n} \right\Vert_\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

Let's consider functional $$f: (c, \Vert \cdot\Vert_\infty)\ni (x_n) \rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_n-\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} x_n}{2^n}$$

where $c$ is a space of convergent sequences.

I want to calculate $\Vert f \Vert$.

**My work so far**

Let's denote $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }x_n = g$, then

$$f(x_n) = \frac{x_1-g}{2} + \frac{x_2-g}{2^2} + \frac{x_3-g}{2^3} + ... \le \frac{\Vert x_n \Vert_\infty - g}{2}+ \frac{\Vert x_n \Vert_\infty - g}{4}+ \frac{\Vert x_n \Vert_\infty-g}{8} + ...$$ $$= \Vert x_n\Vert_\infty-g$$

So when it comes to calculate norm I have for $\Vert x_n \Vert_\infty\le 1$:

$$|f(x_n)| \le 1-g$$

So I can see that supremum is hold for such sequnece $x_n$ such we have $|f(x_n)| = 1-g$.

Example of a sequence which satisfies it is $x_n = \frac 1 n$ ( $\Vert x_n \Vert_\infty = 1, \; g =0$)

But! I want to have as big value of $1-g$ as possible for sequence $x_n: \sup_n|x_n| \le 1$

If I'm correct then I'm looking for a sequence $x_n$ which statisfies the supremum condition and maximazes $1 - \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_n$.

Could you please tell me how this sequnece can be chosen, and how can I prove that it really maximazes $1-g$ ?

Comment: Must $g$ be positive? What about $x_1=1$, $x_n=-1000$ for $n\ge2$?

Comment: It doesn't have to be. I see what you saying and you really solved the issue. We just need to take such sequence $(x_n)$ that $x_1 = 1$ and $x_n = M $ for $n \ge 2$. When $1-g=1-m$ can be as much as I want. It means that supremum is not taken by any sequence so the norm doesn't exist. Could you please add this as answer so that I can accept it ?